# How do I pass multiple StringIO into python-pdfkit?

Tags: python, pdf-generation, pdfkit, stringio

Goal: 
- Use django templateing language.
- Render the template in memory (no disk writes).
- Push rendered content to StringIO instance.
- Use instance in python-pdfkit.

Issue:
I keep getting `TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, instance found` when trying to pass more than one file in the list.

The below code works without the `[]` and just one StringIO instance.

from django.template import loader, Context
from django import template
import StringIO

```
STATIC_URL = "https://d1i1yohwujljp9.cloudfront.net/static/"
t = loader.get_template('pdf_coverpage.html')
c = template.Context( {'STATIC_URL': STATIC_URL })
output = StringIO.StringIO()
output.write(t.render(c))
output1 = StringIO.StringIO()
output1.write(t.render(c))

pdfkit.from_file([ output, output1 ] , 'out.pdf' )
```

Traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pdfkit\api.py", line 44, in from_file
    configuration=configuration)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pdfkit\pdfkit.py", line 37, in __init__
    self.source = Source(url_or_file, type_)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pdfkit\source.py", line 12, in __init__
    self.checkFiles()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pdfkit\source.py", line 28, in checkFiles
    if not os.path.exists(path):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\genericpath.py", line 18, in exists
    os.stat(path)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, instance found
```

Comment: Do you have the full stack trace

Comment: @SaikiranYerram Added traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not your fault. This happens because pdf kit assumes each element in the list as a file path instead of file  descriptor.

[here is the relevant code](https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit/blob/master/pdfkit/source.py).

I had a similar situation of HTML spread across multiple templates. I put them all in one string and pass the StringIO to pdfkit. I used CSS to manage page breaks and other wkhtmltopdf formatting options.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  Was just getting ready to post this code change.

Answer (score 0):

Using StringIO doesn't appear to be a recommended approach in the documentation.

I just tried this and it worked fine. Is there a reason you don't want to do it this way?

```
pdfkit.from_url(['google.com', 'yandex.ru', 'engadget.com'], 'out.pdf')
```

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfkit

Comment: I have workers that simply run across the redis queue and didn't want the overhead of hitting our LIVE services with extra thousands of requests.